# regex to match link inside xml with last mod

Tags: regex

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?><urlset xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9">
<url><loc>https://google.com/2020/08/this1.html</loc><lastmod>2020-08-06T11:30:55Z</lastmod></url>
<url><loc>https://google.com/2020/08/this2.html</loc><lastmod>2020-08-05T11:30:06Z</lastmod></url>
<url><loc>https://google.com/2020/08/this3.html</loc><lastmod>2020-08-06T11:29:25Z</lastmod></url>
</lastmod></url></urlset>
```

I'm trying to get links from above xml to get links which has lastmod of 2020-08-06
my regex code is **`https:.+2020-08-05.+<\/url`**

but it ended up getting it all from 1st and last link

I want to match only

```
<url><loc>https://google.com/2020/08/this1.html</loc><lastmod>2020-08-06T11:30:55Z</lastmod></url>
<url><loc>https://google.com/2020/08/this3.html</loc><lastmod>2020-08-06T11:29:25Z</lastmod></url>
```

Comment: Is there any reason why you are using regex for this? I mean, XML isn't made to be parsed with regex.

Comment: `<loc>(.+)<\/loc>.*2020-08-06` - Can you try this.

Comment: I'm using a php script webscrape to get links from xml, thats the only simpler way to do it that I can think of :/

Comment: @rootkonda
thanks for the reply, that only match the first instance, but thanks I'll look it up how to match all instances. THanks

Comment: @rootkonda sorry, that solves it :D, my code wasn't using /g tahts why it only match first thanksss

Comment: @Kenneth - You can use global mode to match all instances. `/<loc>(.+)<\/loc>.*2020-08-06/g`

Comment: @ Kenneth - I will post it as an answer for you to accept.

Comment: @KennethGervacio If you are using php, you could use a parser https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3577641/how-do-you-parse-and-process-html-xml-in-php?rq=1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
/<loc>(.+)<\/loc>.*2020-08-06/g
```

capturing the group between loc tags
Demo and explanation here:
https://regex101.com/r/HBvG3K/8

Answer (score 0):

A very easy and stupid regex - see [regexr](http://regexr.com/5a497):

```
.*<lastmod>2020-08-06.*
```

Comment: my code works its just that the xml wasn't correctly parse?